# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string '

Tags: javascript, jquery, guid, typeerror

I am a attempting to run the below jQuery .on() method with the parameter value of 10 however whenever I do I get an

> Uncaught TypeError

```
 $(document).on("click", '.topic-btn', displayGIF(10));
```

It's my understanding that how it is written runs the function without a click event causing the error.

Is there a way around this? Ultimately, I want the `.on("click"...` for a parameter value of **10** and a `.on("dblcick"...` for a parameter value of **20**.

Comment: `displayGIF()` is called immediately. Use `, function() { displayGIF(10) }` syntax.

Comment: $(document).on("click", ".topic-btn", function(){ displayGIF(10); });or else  $(".topic-btn").on("click", function(){ displayGIF(10); })

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the code to this:

```
$(document).on("click", '.topic-btn', {'param': 10}, function(event){
     displayGIF(event.data.param);
});
```

The data to on can be passed using the above method. Refer docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to invoke function displayGIF with parameter 10 or 20 based on click on dbclick. If that is the case then you can write

```
  $(".topic-btn").on("click", function(){
                                        displayGIF(10);
                                        });
```